In Python unittest log testname, expected value and actual value into a separate file
I have used the standard python unittest framework to create a testsuite for my hardware that read values from sensors. A test might look like below (a bit simplified)
def test_temperature1(self):
   self.assertAlmostEqual(self.temp_sensor1.get_value(),25.0, delta=1)

I would be able to both run the test as unittest with success/fail but also log the actual and expect values into a file. I understand this is possible by adding log statements to each test case but it would be preferable to use a testrunner or another unittest framework that supports this out of the box since I dont want to rewrite all my tests.

It ended up with a new LoggedTestCase class inheriting from unittest.TestCase. I  override the methods used like assertAlmostEqual. There I store the first, second and assertion into a member variable.  My implemented unittests inherits from my derived LoggedTestCase class.
I also created an inherited class LoggedTestResult inheriting from unittest.TextTestResult. In this file stopTestRun, addSuccess and addFailure is overridden. In stopTestRun a file is created and in addSuccess and addFailure output is generated.
To run all this a new LoggedTestRunner inherited from unittest.TextTestRunner is created that uses the LoggedTestResult.
